# VSTO Activate Backstage tab

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop

How do we programmatically activate a custom backstage tab. basically I want to show my own backstage tab for any save, saveas tasks.

looks like `ActivateTab()` doesn't work for backstage. and there were few suggestion about `SendKeys`, which isn't reliable.

Comment: Anyone?   I'm having the same Issue.